# Design for circular dependency

Tags: java, circular-dependency

This is a question about how to **better** handle circular dependency. Let me preface by saying I think circular dependency is rarely necessary, but the code is handed down to me and I can't help it.

Suppose there is a circular dependency on classes with a conceptually equal standing, ie there is no apparent "owns" relation between them. How do I handle them gracefully?

Lets take an example where we want to represent a mutable topology of rooms, with `neighbour` a reflexive property

```
interface Room {
    public void remove(Room r);
}

class Living implements Room {
    Room[] neighbour;
    public void remove(Room r) {/* implementation */}
}

class Dining implements Room {
    Room[] neighbour;
    public void remove(Room r) {/* implementation */}
}
```

Now, clearly we cannot call `remove` on the other `Room` in the implementation of `remove`, this is obviously endless recursion. But then I am left with a few options:

- Make one `Room` own another, somehow document the fact, and then only one type of `Room` has the `remove` capability.
- Make a second method `removeSelf`, where it never calls the methods of the other `Room`, thereby resolving the infinite recursion.
- Have a `Building` object higher on the hierarchy and have it do all the operations on `Room`

And their respective disadvantages are

- Very counter-intuitive and imposes an artificial structure when there is none. Also, at least one owning `Room` must exist within some neighbour.
- Adds a method that should never be called by users, this sucks as an interface.
- Requires an owning object, sometimes also a very awkward structure, a `Building` is only coincidentally fitting to be an owning object.

So, the question, what is a better design if circular dependency is somehow unavoidable?

We could probably make a `RoomOperator` class containing functions to operate on `Room`s, but it also suffers the same problems as the `removeSelf` method above: it eventually calls a method that is illegal outside of `RoomOperator`.

Comment: You're hinting at the problem.  Trying to manage aggregate properties like "neighbor" from the pov of a single object is brittle as you've clearly discovered. This is one of the traps easily possible in OO models. The solution here is probably to implement a `RoomManager` object that takes care of functions like `Remove` outside the `Room` hierarchy. Hopefully you're using dependency injection, so you can inject that as needed.

Comment: I see the need of another class which can help you to manage `Room`s because remove Room from Room doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, I hinted at that solution in a later edit, but what bothers me about that is it eventually calls a method in the interface that should never be called other than by the `RoomManager`

Comment: What are you allowed to change? Which part is handed down to you?

Comment: The dependency structure of the classes is handed down, unlikely to change. Also, I would suppose this be a necessary problem sometimes outside of being forced?

Comment: It is a necessary problem, as you put it, but I would make changes to the interface, or even replace it with an abstract class. Possibly change the data structure holding the neighbours. Can these be done? Not sure what "dependency structure" is: Inheritance? Composition?

Comment: Also, your `Remove` methods methods should be renamed to `remove` and use the `public` modifier.

Comment: `public` is just me being lazy :P edited

Comment: Change it from RoomManager to `Building` and you have my vote.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Huh? Change what RoomManager?

Comment: @user1803551 The structure being the `neighbor` property is inside the `Room`s themselves. This excludes the possibility of having a neighbouring table independent of `Room`

Comment: And the interface?

Comment: @PasserBy Manager classes are not very OO. But in this case, there is a very logical concept for something that contains multiple Rooms. It's called a Building. So rather than calling this class a `RoomManager`, you should all it a `Building`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the point about `Building` is that there might not be such a logical object. For instance, what would be the owning object for multiple `Building`s? At some point there will be no such object

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: Not really, all solutions has some of what was mentioned as not ideal. There might not exist *the* solution, but I am hoping for a larger improvement over what was available.

Comment: You should comment on the answers with that info. From the details you give in the question, both answers are valid solutions.

Comment: Also, use @username to reply to comments.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Add functionality to the rooms, allowing them to tell if they need to ask the neighbour to remove them or not, thus avoiding recursion.

```
interface Room {
    void remove(Room r);

    void removeOther(Room r);
}

class Living implements Room {
    List<Room> neighbours;

    @Override
    public void remove(Room r) {
        r.removeOther(this);
        neighbours.remove(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeOther(Room r) {
        neighbours.remove(r);
    }
}
```

The method `removeOther(Room r)` tells the room to only remove the supplied room from its list. This is in contrast to the `remove(Room r)` method, which also causes the room to ask the supplied room to remove it.

This solution keeps the interface method intact if that's important. I would actually make the various rooms extends an `AbstractRoom` class instead and add both methods' implementations there. But since both of your given `Room`s are the same it's hard to know what to do exactly.

If you can change the method to `remove(Room r, boolean callback)` you could save a bit confusion and use only that method.

I also changed `neighbours` to a list just for ease of use.

### Solution 2

Use an external manager (utility) class. This class allows removes the need for the rooms to manage each other.

```
interface Room {
    void remove(Room r);

    List<Room> getNeighbours();
}

class Living implements Room {

    List<Room> neighbours;

    @Override
    public void remove(Room r) {
        RoomManager.removeRooms(r, this);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Room> getNeighbours() {
        return neighbours;
    }
}

class RoomManager {

    static void removeRooms(Room r1, Room r2) {
        r1.getNeighbours().remove(r2);
        r2.getNeighbours().remove(r1);
    }
}
```

Again, I add a method to the interface in order to unify the composition of the rooms. An abstract class would do better here.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a base class `RoomSupport` which manages all the dependencies. Other implementations should extend `RoomSupport`. Here the implementation:

```
abstract class RoomSupport implements Room {
    private final Set<Room> neighbours = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void addNeighbour(Room r) {
        if (neighbours.add(r)) {
            r.addNeighbour(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Room r) {
        if (neighbours.remove(r)) {
            r.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation takes care, that *adding* and *removing* does terminate and no cyclic dependencies at all.